# WordPress Admin Page Scope Problem - Menu Shows, Page Text Won't Render

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins, scope

Wordpress 5.1, Ubuntu 18.04 VBox on Windows Host

I created a plugin "Example Admin Page"

I've gotten the menu items to appear, but the pages render blank, rather than showing the html "Welcome..." text suggested below in the code. I know it's a scope problem, but I'm not exactly sure how to approach it.
Yes, I could take it all outside the class and it renders, but it's supposed to be good practice to use classes, so I'd rather do it this way. I would be grateful for a method of how to proceed properly.

```
class EAP_Example_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this,'my_admin_menu'));
    }

    function my_admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page( 'Example Admin Page', 'EAP Menu', 'manage_options', 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-page.php', 'eap_admin_page', 'dashicons-tickets', '9999' );
        add_submenu_page( 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-page.php', 'Example Admin Sub Page', 'EAP Sub Menu', 'manage_options', 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-sub-page.php', 'eap_admin_sub_page' ); 
    }

    function eap_admin_page(){
        echo '<h2>Welcome To Example Admin Page</h2>';
    }

    function eap_admin_sub_page(){
        echo '<h2>Welcome To Example Admin Sub Page</h2>';
    }

}

// Setup and initialize the admin page.
$eap_admin_page_startup = new EAP_Example_Widget();
```

Answer (score 0):

It was absolutely a scope issue.

In order to call a function from within another function, I had to self-reference the class EAP_Example_Widget.

For instance, instead of just 'eap_admin_page' for the callable function, it needed to be:

```
__CLASS__ .'::eap_admin_page'.
```

See fixed example below. Now it works.

```
class EAP_Example_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this,'my_admin_menu'));
    }

    function my_admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page( 'Example Admin Page', 'EAP Menu', 'manage_options', 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-page.php', __CLASS__ .'::eap_admin_page', 'dashicons-tickets', '9999' );
        add_submenu_page( 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-page.php', 'Example Admin Sub Page', 'EAP Sub Menu', 'manage_options', 'eap-plugin/eap-admin-sub-page.php', __CLASS__ .'::eap_admin_sub_page' ); 
    }

    function eap_admin_page(){
        echo '<h2>Welcome To Example Admin Page</h2>';
    }

    function eap_admin_sub_page(){
        echo '<h2>Welcome To Example Admin Sub Page</h2>';
    }

}

// Setup and initialize the admin page.
$eap_admin_page_startup = new EAP_Example_Widget();
```